# ASP.NET Boilerplate Framework with ADO.NET

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

How to use ADO.NET with the multi tenant application. I would like to to use ado.net with SQL server. please advise if there are any samples.

Comment: I do not think so it will come with ADO.Net 
because they have created framework and by default they have provided entity framework code first approach

Answer (score 2):

Just create a [custom repository](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core#custom-repositories) and use SQL inside it.

Check this article for more: http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Using-Stored-Procedures,-User-Defined-Functions-and-Views/index.html
It also uses SP and views.

Comment: Thank You for creating the excellent framework. I will try this and let you know. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are:

- EF Core
- EF
- Dapper
- NHibernate

If performance is top priority for you [Dapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dapper_ORM) may be of interest.